# Simulation of CONNECT BY PRIOR of Oracle in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I get the functionality of CONNECT BY PRIOR of Oracle in SQL Server 2000/2005/2008?

Comment: Since you seem to want more details, you'll have to tell us some table structure data and what you're trying to do. If you have an existing Oracle query, that'd be a good start....

Comment: @John, see the URL I posted in my answer, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/db2/library/techarticle/dm-0510rielau/ -- it shows how CONNECT BY PRIOR works (a nice but Oracle-proprietary syntax for getting tree structures) and how to get the same effect with (recursive) common table expressions, that is, the WITH keyword (which is a SQL standard and implemented in IBM DB2, Microsoft SQL Server, and the open-source PostgreSQL engine in release 8.4).

Comment: @Alex: thanks, I saw your post and read the article. Pretty nice article, and I can see why Oracle users might like the Oracle syntax. I prefer the standard syntax, as it's more general.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The SQL standard way to implement recursive queries, as implemented e.g. by IBM DB2 and [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx), is the `WITH` clause. See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/db2/library/techarticle/dm-0510rielau/) for one example of translating a `CONNECT BY` into a `WITH` (technically a *recursive CTE*) -- the example is for DB2 but I believe it will work on SQL Server as well.

Edit: apparently the original querant requires a specific example, here's one from the IBM site whose URL I already gave. Given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE emp(empid  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                 name   VARCHAR(10),
                 salary DECIMAL(9, 2),
                 mgrid  INTEGER);
```

where `mgrid` references an employee's manager's `empid`, the task is, get the names of everybody who reports directly or indirectly to `Joan`. In Oracle, that's a simple `CONNECT`:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM emp
  START WITH name = 'Joan'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR empid = mgrid
```

In SQL Server, IBM DB2, or PostgreSQL 8.4 (as well as in the SQL standard, for what that's worth;-), the perfectly equivalent solution is instead a recursive query (more complex syntax, but, actually, even more power and flexibility):

```
WITH n(empid, name) AS 
   (SELECT empid, name 
    FROM emp
    WHERE name = 'Joan'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT nplus1.empid, nplus1.name 
    FROM emp as nplus1, n
    WHERE n.empid = nplus1.mgrid)
SELECT name FROM n
```

Oracle's `START WITH` clause becomes the first nested `SELECT`, the base case of the recursion, to be `UNION`ed with the recursive part which is just another `SELECT`.

SQL Server's specific flavor of `WITH` is of course documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(SQL.90).aspx), which also gives guidelines and limitations for using this keyword, as well as several examples.

Comment: Please explain with an example.

E.g. 

Take some countries and states

Like

India
  --State1
  -- State2

Australia
  --AusState1
  --AusStae2

I am looking for the exact query

Comment: **F** section at [this url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) was what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there any way to add the level to this?

Answer (score 13):

`@Alex Martelli`'s answer is great!
But it work only for one element at time (`WHERE name = 'Joan'`)
If you take out the `WHERE` clause, the query will return all the root rows together...

I changed a little bit for my situation, so it can show the entire tree for a table.

table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mar_categories] ( 
    [category]  int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name]      varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [level]     int NOT NULL,
    [action]    int NOT NULL,
    [parent]    int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [XPK_mar_categories] PRIMARY KEY([category])
)
```

(`level` is literally the level of a category 0: root, 1: first level after root, ...)

and the query:

```
WITH n(category, name, level, parent, concatenador) AS 
(
    SELECT category, name, level, parent, '('+CONVERT(VARCHAR (MAX), category)+' - '+CONVERT(VARCHAR (MAX), level)+')' as concatenador
    FROM mar_categories
    WHERE parent is null
        UNION ALL
    SELECT m.category, m.name, m.level, m.parent, n.concatenador+' * ('+CONVERT (VARCHAR (MAX), case when ISNULL(m.parent, 0) = 0 then 0 else m.category END)+' - '+CONVERT(VARCHAR (MAX), m.level)+')' as concatenador
    FROM mar_categories as m, n
    WHERE n.category = m.parent
)
SELECT distinct * FROM n ORDER BY concatenador asc
```

(You don't need to concatenate the `level` field, I did just to make more readable)

the answer for this query should be something like:

[image: sql return]

I hope it helps someone!

now, I'm wondering how to do this on MySQL... ^^

Comment: i had a weird issue adapting your code, with an non-the same data types on the delimiter and recursive column.... but it sorted out, just with defining the first one length explicitly.... thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it possible to avoid path building from string (`concatenador`) for get tree like structure (so each sub-leaf values grouped together without holes by another elements)? Oracle `connect by` build in such way for free.

Comment: I don't get it, isn't the whole point of a `connect by` query for it to provide the `level` and not you.

Comment: @Superdooperhero As I comment on my answer: "(You don't need to concatenate the level field, I did just to make more readable)"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used connect by prior, but a quick search shows it's used for tree structures.  In SQL Server, you use common table expressions to get similar functionality.

Comment: Please explain with an example.

E.g. 

Take some countries and states

Like

India
  --State1
  -- State2

Australia
  --AusState1
  --AusStae2