# Recursive handling sql

Tags: sql, recursion

I have a table which has three columns `element A`, `element B`, and `dueDate`.  If I have the following three rows:

```
A | B | 01/01/2010
B | C | 01/01/2011
C | D | 01/01/2012
```

then I would like to be able to extract the following assumption 
->A | D | 01/01/2012 either by using plain sql, or by using java to manipulate the data fetched from the database.

Thanks

Comment: what database engine and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what database you are using. In `Oracle`, for example, you can check out the [start with / connect by feature](http://www.oradev.com/connect_by.jsp), which is really nice for hierarchical queries.

For `SQL Server`, you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server) for a similar idea.

Other databases have similar mechanisms, you just need to research it to figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: To complete the picture: The recursive common table expression is supported by Firebird, PostgreSQL, H2 Database, DB2 and Teradata. It is also supported in the newest Oracle release (11gR2) in addition to the connect by queries