# Recursive-like queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to figure out how to perform what would essentially be a recursive query in SQL. I've got two tables;

```
TABLE Object(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)

TABLE ObjectDependency(
object_id INT,
dependency_id INT,
FOREIGN KEY(object_id)     REFERENCES Object(id)
FOREIGN KEY(dependency_id) REFERENCES Object(id)
)
```

I want to write a stored procedure that will take an object id and spit out all of the objects dependancies (something like this, but also any found dependency's dependency.

```
SELECT id, ObjectDependency.id FROM Object
JOIN ObjectDependency ON object_id = id
```

The system is set up in such a way that there are no cyclical dependancies, but I'm kind of lost on how I would manage to loop all results into one stored procedure.

Comment: If only you had access to recursive CTEs ... ;-)

Comment: To this, there are different solutions for different database products (Oracle/Mysql/PostgreSQL/MS SQL/...). Which one are you using?

Comment: SQL Server, sorry, I'm a little lost in the world of databases.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server

Comment: But which **VERSION** of SQL Server are you using??

Answer (score 2):

If you're on SQL Server 2005 or newer, you can use a **recursive CTE** (Common Table Expression) to do this (see [MSDN Books Online docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) for more details).

Basically, it's an "inline view" - a view that only exists for the next statement. One version of the CTE is designed specifically to handle recursive scenarios.

It looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RecurseObjects @ObjectID INT
AS BEGIN
  WITH ObjectCTE AS 
  (
      -- set the anchor - select the object defined
      SELECT o.id AS 'ID', CAST(NULL AS INT) AS 'ParentID', 1 AS 'Level'
      FROM dbo.Object o
      WHERE o.id = @ObjectID

      -- add recursion
      UNION ALL

      SELECT o2.id AS 'ID', cte.id AS 'ParentID', cte.Level + 1 AS 'Level'
      FROM dbo.Object o2
      INNER JOIN dbo.ObjectDependency od ON od.dependency_id = o2.id
      INNER JOIN ObjectCTE cte ON cte.id = od.object_id
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM ObjectCTE
END
```

So this recursive CTE is run in stages:

- the first "run" sets the anchor, that is, the first `SELECT` is executed and the results are stored in a temporary result set
- then, the recursion is handled: the second select is run, basically selecting all rows that are dependent from the row(s) selected in the first run - all those that are linked like this:

  ```
  object.id --> objectdepedency.dependecy_id 
                objectdepedency.object_id --> "parent" object.id
  ```

This second step is repeated over and over, until no more additional rows are retrieved - then the result set is returned.