# Simulation of CONNECT BY PRIOR of Oracle in SQL Server... in a subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This question is a extension of a previous question [Simulation of CONNECT BY PRIOR of ORACLE in SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server).

From that I know how to do a CONNECT BY in SQL Server. In Oracle you can use a connect by easily in a sub query.

So in Oracle I can do
select * from t1 where t1.id in (select from connect by query).

Is that also possible in SQL server? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server (and other databases as well) you will need to use a [recursive common table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175972%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) expression, something like:

```
with some_tree as ( 
    select ...
    union all
    select ...
)
select * 
from t1 
where t1.id in (select some_id from some_tree);
```

Since version 11.2 Oracle does also support recursive common table expresions (so you could use the same syntax on both databases)