# how to deal with "Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)."

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i was asked to Create script that will expect whoever runs it to provide an employee id. Locate all employees that the provided employee supervises in any depth.

My code is :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNames] (@V uniqueidentifier)  
RETURNS @OldNames TABLE (EMP_NAME varchar(50))
 AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @master uniqueidentifier
    SET @master=(SELECT EMP_Supervisor FROM Employee WHERE EMP_ID=@v)
    IF @master=NULL return

    INSERT INTO @OldNames(EMP_NAME)
        SELECT (SELECT EMP_NAME FROM Employee WHERE EMP_ID = @master)
        FROM Employee
        UNION
        SELECT EMP_NAME FROM GetNames(@master)
     RETURN
END
```

And when i want to see if it works, i execute this :

```
SELECT * from GetNames('561e2d88-a747-460f-99e1-cfb1d3d8ca5c')
```

where "*561e2d88-a747-460f-99e1-cfb1d3d8ca5c*" is an ui of an employee and i get this as an exception:

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level
>   exceeded (limit 32).

can you please help me? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What database are you using? Using recursion in a stored procedure is a sure way to get into trouble, and a bad design to start with. What you are looking for is a way to search in a hierarchy. There are multiple ways to do this, some of which depend on the particular SQL dialect you are using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server (this appears to be SQL server consider using the with statement as in the example linked

Comment: Seems highly unusual to have an employee->manager hierarchy with 32 levels anyway. Sure you don't have a cycle in the data?

Comment: I m using SQL Server 
I was given a database and asked to Create script that will expect whoever runs it to provide an employee id. Locate all employees that the provided employee supervises in any depth, as i wrote earlier. 

and the employee table is this : 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
 [EMP_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [EMP_Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
 [EMP_DateOfHire] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [EMP_Supervisor] [uniqueidentifier] NULL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say you are using SQL Server

Have a look at the following example

```
DECLARE @EmployeeStructure TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Name VARCHAR(MAX),
        ManagerID INT
)

INSERT INTO @EmployeeStructure SELECT 1, 'a', NULL
INSERT INTO @EmployeeStructure SELECT 2, 'b', 1
INSERT INTO @EmployeeStructure SELECT 3, 'c', 1
INSERT INTO @EmployeeStructure SELECT 4, 'd', 2
INSERT INTO @EmployeeStructure SELECT 5, 'e', 2
INSERT INTO @EmployeeStructure SELECT 6, 'f', 2

DECLARE @EmployeeID INT = 2

;WITH Employee AS (
        SELECT  Name, ID
        FROM    @EmployeeStructure e 
        WHERE   ManagerID = @EmployeeID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  es.Name,
                es.ID
        FROM    Employee e INNER JOIN
                @EmployeeStructure es   ON  e.ID = es.ManagerID
)
SELECT  Name
FROM    Employee
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13533)

Further to that maybe have a look at

[Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Also,

[Query Hints (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)

> MAXRECURSION number
>
> Specifies the maximum number of recursions allowed for this query.
>   number is a nonnegative integer between 0 and 32767. When 0 is
>   specified, no limit is applied. If this option is not specified, the
>   default limit for the server is 100.
>
> When the specified or default number for MAXRECURSION limit is reached
>   during query execution, the query is ended and an error is returned.
>
> Because of this error, all effects of the statement are rolled back.
>   If the statement is a SELECT statement, partial results or no results
>   may be returned. Any partial results returned may not include all rows
>   on recursion levels beyond the specified maximum recursion level.

Comment: This is a nice example but the id and the manager type is uniqueidentifier not int..