# How to improve user defined function with while on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 UDF which performs a kind of recursive loop. I mean, I have a table called Employees where in one of my columns I store another Employee id (his boss).

When I get an employee id, I must be able to know the whole department below him. For example:
Employee Joe (ID:1) works for Robert (ID:2)
Employee Robert (ID:2) works for Michelle (ID:3)

I must be able to count the salary (let's suppose it's on the same table) of all employees below Michelle, i.e. Robert and Joe.

Up to now, I created a UDF that returns a table with all employee ids below Michelle and use an EXISTS clause on the queries' where but it performs very poorly.

Do you guys have another idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Forgot to said I use a while loop on the UDF to retreive every employee

Comment: Not sure in your case, but if you need hierarchical data you follow this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server)

Comment: You should probably be using a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.90).aspx) rather than a `WHILE` loop. Explicit looping is rarely the best way to achieve performance. Can't offer an example though, because you've not shown us any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a recursive [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) rather than a `WHILE` loop to find all of the employees. I don't have your tables or data so I've made some up:

```
create table Employees (
    ID int not null primary key,
    Name varchar(20) not null,
    BigBossID int null foreign key references Employees(ID),
    Salary decimal(18,4) not null
)
go
insert into Employees (ID,Name,BigBossID,Salary) values
(1,'Joe',2,2.50),
(2,'Robert',3,19000.75),
(3,'Michelle',null,1234567890.00)
```

And then I can use this query to find all employees below Michelle:

```
declare @RootID int
set @RootID = 3
;With EmployeesBelowRoot as (
    select ID from Employees where BigBossID = @RootID
    union all
    select e.ID from Employees e inner join EmployeesBelowRoot ebr on e.BigBossID = ebr.ID
)
select SUM(Salary) from Employees where ID in (select ID from EmployeesBelowRoot)
```

You could (if you think it's worth it) place the CTE (`EmployeesBelowRoot`) into a UDF and call it with `@RootID` as a parameter, but I've just put it directly in the query for now.