# combine and remove value from database

Tags: ios, sql, parent-child, inner-join, union

I have Question_Master and Assessment_Master table. In question_Master i have questions parent-child relationship. When i answer the parent question, When i filter the answered button filter i need to display parent along with child. When i answer the child question, When i filter the answered button filter i need to display parent along with child. But my issue is, when i answer the both question i'm getting child duplicate.

when answer the parent question it get parent-child:

```
  SELECT a.QM_ID,a.QM_QCM_ID,
       a.QM_Question,a.QM_Type,
       a.QM_Parent_Id,
       c.AM_Answer, 
       c.AM_Comments 
  FROM question_master a 
       INNER JOIN Assessment_master c 
             ON (c.AM_QM_ID = a.QM_ID 
                 AND c.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
                 AND c.AM_HM_ID = %d 
                 AND c.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@) 
 WHERE a.QM_Parent_Id = 0 
       AND a.QM_Status = 'A' 
       AND a.QM_QCM_ID = %@ 
       AND a.QM_QRM_Id = %@

UNION
SELECT b.QM_ID,
       b.QM_QCM_ID,
       b.QM_Question,
       b.QM_Type,
       b.QM_Parent_Id,
       null, 
       null 
  FROM question_master b 
       INNER JOIN Assessment_master d 
             ON (d. AM_QM_ID = b.QM_Parent_Id 
                 AND d.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_HM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@) 
 WHERE b.QM_Parent_Id != 0 
       AND b.QM_Status = 'A' 
       AND b.QM_QCM_ID = %@ 
       AND b.QM_QRM_Id = %@
```

when i answer the child question it get parent-child:

```
    SELECT a.QM_ID,a.QM_QCM_ID,
       a.QM_Question,a.QM_Type,
       a.QM_Parent_Id,
       c.AM_Answer, 
       c.AM_Comments 
  FROM question_master a 
       INNER JOIN Assessment_master c 
             ON (c.AM_QM_ID = a.QM_ID 
                 AND c.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
                 AND c.AM_HM_ID = %d 
                 AND c.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@) 
 WHERE a.QM_Parent_Id = 0 
       AND a.QM_Status = 'A' 
       AND a.QM_QCM_ID = %@ 
       AND a.QM_QRM_Id = %@

UNION
SELECT b.QM_ID,
       b.QM_QCM_ID,
       b.QM_Question,
       b.QM_Type,
       b.QM_Parent_Id,
       d.AM_Answer, 
       d.AM_Comments 
  FROM question_master b 
       INNER JOIN Assessment_master d 
             ON (d. AM_QM_ID = b.QM_ID 
                 AND d.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_HM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@) 
 WHERE b.QM_Parent_Id IN (SELECT QM_ID 
                            FROM question_master 
                           WHERE QM_Parent_Id = 0 
                                 AND QM_Status = 'A' 
                                 AND QM_QCM_ID = %@ 
                                 AND QM_QRM_Id = %@)
```

I used combined query from above:

```
 SELECT a.QM_ID,a.QM_QCM_ID,
       a.QM_Question,a.QM_Type,
       a.QM_Parent_Id,
       c.AM_Answer, 
       c.AM_Comments 
  FROM question_master a 
       INNER JOIN Assessment_master c 
             ON (c.AM_QM_ID = a.QM_ID 
                 AND c.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
                 AND c.AM_HM_ID = %d 
                 AND c.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@) 
 WHERE a.QM_Parent_Id = 0 
       AND a.QM_Status = 'A' 
       AND a.QM_QCM_ID = %@ 
       AND a.QM_QRM_Id = %@

UNION
SELECT b.QM_ID,
       b.QM_QCM_ID,
       b.QM_Question,
       b.QM_Type,
       b.QM_Parent_Id,
       null, 
       null 
  FROM question_master b 
       INNER JOIN Assessment_master d 
             ON (d. AM_QM_ID = b.QM_Parent_Id 
                 AND d.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_HM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@) 
 WHERE b.QM_Parent_Id != 0 
       AND b.QM_Status = 'A' 
       AND b.QM_QCM_ID = %@ 
       AND b.QM_QRM_Id = %@

UNION
SELECT b.QM_ID,
       b.QM_QCM_ID,
       b.QM_Question,
       b.QM_Type,
       b.QM_Parent_Id,
       d.AM_Answer, 
       d.AM_Comments 
  FROM question_master b 
       INNER JOIN Assessment_master d 
             ON (d. AM_QM_ID = b.QM_ID 
                 AND d.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_HM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@) 
 WHERE b.QM_Parent_Id IN (SELECT QM_ID 
                            FROM question_master 
                           WHERE QM_Parent_Id = 0 
                                 AND QM_Status = 'A' 
                                 AND QM_QCM_ID = %@ 
                                 AND QM_QRM_Id = %@)
```

But here i'm getting extra child duplicate value. When i use LEFT it getting all the child question, if i use EXCEPT then answer the parent question it don't getting parent-child relation.

Question_Master:

```
QM_ID    QM_QRM_ID   QM_LCM_ID  QM_QCM_ID   QM_Question       QM_Parent_Id

432         5            19       1         question_parent       0
433         5            19       1         question_child        432
434         5            19       1           question_child1      432
```

Assessment_Master:

```
AM_ID     AM_UM_ID   AM_ASM_Local_Id  AM_QM_ID   AM_Answer   AM_Comments  AM_HNM_ID
1          8            1                433       NULL        testing      1
```

If i answer the child question 433 and i'm getting only parent with 433 child. I'm not getting 434 question.

```
a.QM_ID  a.QM_QCM_ID  a.QM_Question     a.QM_Parent_Id c.AM_Answer  c.AM_Comments
         432       1          question_parent     0                Null        NULL
          433      1          question_child       432             null        value
```

Comment: Do the %d %@ come from Objective-C wherefore the iOS thing would significant? And what do they mean? The same value each or some sequence of values?

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. It's like a printf format.

Comment: @albe: Can you give the answer?

Comment: I would need a few things: What db engine are you using (PostgreSQL)? as @Ziouas points out this seems to be a hierarchical thing and that is important. Also what parameters you are passing and a small sample of related data.

Comment: I can't able to post my images..

Comment: @albe: check my edited code with table. I answered child question. It saved to Assessment_Master table. If i filter the query it won't getting parent-child. I need to display all the question. The QM_ID 432,433,434. Because these are all parent-child realtioship.

Comment: Is this a SQLite database? If so what version? `file (db file name).db` from command line gives this. What is filling in the parameters %d and %@. why %@ when the values look numeric?

Answer (score 0):

Which database engine are you using?

Have you tried recurrence to create a simple parent-child relationship?

If ORACLE then take a look at CONNECT BY PRIOR,

if MS SQL then here is equivalent: [Simulation of CONNECT BY PRIOR of ORACLE in SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server).

You won't have to use any union and the results will be much easier to filter and work with.

Comment: This is for objective-c. Above query is for iOS development. I fetched all the data from server and stored in local database. Then i'm writing query for parent-child. But i'm getting problem.

Comment: check my edited code with table. I answered child question. It saved to Assessment_Master table. If i filter the query it won't getting parent-child. I need to display all the question. The QM_ID 432,433,434. Because these are all parent-child realtioship

Comment: Objective-c ok, but which database engine? Have you tried recursive query?

Comment: Client used SOAP webservie for server data. I'm fetching using TBXML parser library

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the following:

- you are using SQLite or MySQL
- the last line in question master has qm_id 434 not 433 (otherwise I don't see a primary key)
- you want to display everything in one row and children don't have children of their own

Then this gives what you asked for in your comment (The QM_ID 432,433,434):

```
SELECT a.QM_ID,GROUP_CONCAT(b.QM_ID) 
FROM question_master a JOIN 
     question_master b ON a.QM_ID = b.QM_PARENT_ID
GROUP BY a.QM_ID;
```

Add whatever you need from the assessment_master. If you have a deeper hierarchy, this is again different on different platforms. If you want them on separate lines, that is simple.

Comment: If i run your query it will getting all the questions. I don't want this. If i answer the 433 question. I need to get only parent_id 432 child. I don't want to show all other.

Comment: If i answer the child question 433 and i'm getting only parent with 433 child. I'm not getting 434 question. check edited code and final combine table.