# Need to write a sql statement that find all sub organization records to the parent organization

Tags: sql

I need to write a sql statement that find all sub records which has many level meaning the parent record has 2nd level and 3rd level child records tying to the parent organization. So far I wrote

```
SELECT *
  FROM tblOrganization
  where Parent_Org_ID = '11111'
```

How can I write a sql statement that will give me all the child records (2nd, 3rd level so on) tying to the parent ID record?

Thanks

Comment: Please mention the database you are using. And it is recommended to show what you have done so far, so we can start from there.

Comment: If you're using SQL server, you'll want to use a recursive common table expression.

Comment: And the table structure won't hurt either.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample data set with field names of your parent child relationship?

Comment: and also show some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score -3):

You will need to look for an alternative to Oracle Connect By prior in SQL Server,
the following link answers your requirement.

[Simulation of CONNECT BY PRIOR of ORACLE in SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server)