# store hierarchy information in a MS Access DB for faster queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-administration

I'm trying to figure out how I can store hierarchical type information in a MS Access DB so that queries will be faster. An use case example might make more sense.

- I have a table that has two fields

  1. a name
  2. a hierarchy
- a hierarchy is an X # of level folder structure:

  - `\a\b\c\d`
  - `\a\b\c\d\e`
  - `\a\b\c\d\f\g`
  - `\a\b\h`
  - `\a\b\i\j`
  - you get the idea
- the table will be filled with 300,000 rows
- each row will have a name and a hierarchy

At this point:

- if I want to find all the names that are in a hierarchy, including sub-hierarchies I can run a like query: `where [hierarchy] like '\a\b\*'`
- I can even do wildcard joins even though MS Access's query design GUI doesn't handle it and I have to use the SQL view: `join on [hierarchy] like '\a\b\*'`.

But it can be very slow. Especially if my joins get complex.

So I thought maybe there is a way to create another table that would all the hierarchies and it would maintain parent/child relationships and the first table would reference a row in it. And then, somehow, I could use it to find rows in the first table that match hierarchies and sub-hierarchies in the second table.

However, I have no clue if this is even possible and how I would go about it. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle we use the hierarchal structure where each row has a reference to its parent. Then with the CONNECT BY clause you can connect these rows to each-other.

You should take a look here: [simulation of connect-by in sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server)

Comment: Sounds like I have to use recursive calls which has bad performance, especially because my hierarchy will have multiple levels. Thank you!

Comment: These structure is perfectly capable of storing multiple levels. And the right query gives all the results in one call... So i don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: if I want all names in a parent hierarchy then I'd have to make multiple calls -- one for each sub folder. right?

Comment: No. Read this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions164.htm and this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm There are equivalent SQL statements possible in other DB's

Comment: It looks like MS Access does not have this functionality. Thank you for your help!