# SQL Server Equivalent of Oracle 'CONNECT BY PRIOR', and 'ORDER SIBLINGS BY'

Tags: sql-server, oracle, recursive-query, siblings, connect-by

I've got this Oracle code *structure* I'm trying to convert to SQL Server 2008 *(**Note:** I have used generic names, enclosed column names and table names within square brackets '[]', and done some formatting to make the code more readable)*:

```
SELECT [col#1], [col#2], [col#3], ..., [col#n], [LEVEL] 
FROM (SELECT [col#1], [col#2], [col#3], ..., [col#n] 
      FROM [TABLE_1] 
      WHERE ... ) 
CONNECT BY PRIOR [col#1] = [col#2] 
START WITH [col#2] IS NULL 
ORDER SIBLINGS BY [col#3]
```

What is the SQL Server equivalent *template* of the above code?

Specifically, I'm struggling with the **LEVEL**, and 'ORDER ***SIBLINGS*** BY' Oracle constructs.

**Note:** 
The above "code" is the final output from a set of Oracle procedures. Basically, the ***'WHERE' clause is built up dynamically*** and changes depending on various parameters passed. The *code block starting with 'CONNECT BY PRIOR' is hard-coded*.

---

**For Reference:**

The [Simulation of CONNECT BY PRIOR of ORACLE in SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server) article comes close, but it does not explain how to handle the 'LEVEL' and the 'ORDER SIBLINGS' constructs. ... And my mind is getting in a twist!

```
SELECT name 
  FROM emp
  START WITH name = 'Joan'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR empid = mgrid
```

equates to:

```
WITH n(empid, name) AS 
   (SELECT empid, name 
    FROM emp
    WHERE name = 'Joan'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT nplus1.empid, nplus1.name 
    FROM emp as nplus1, n
    WHERE n.empid = nplus1.mgrid)
SELECT name FROM n
```

---

If I have an initial template to work from, it will go a long way to helping me construct SQL Server stored procs to build up a correct T-SQL statement.

Assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: The equivalent is a recursive common table expression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+recursive-query

Comment: This is an excerpt directly from Oracle stored proc: vSQL := 'SELECT FLEX_VALUE, DESCRIPTION, ADMIN_ENABLED, PARENT_FLEX_VALUE, DISPLAY_DESC, LEVEL FROM ('||
    'SELECT FLEX_VALUE, DESCRIPTION, ADMIN_ENABLED, PARENT_FLEX_VALUE, '||vDescField||' AS DISPLAY_DESC '||
    'FROM GL_SEGMENT'||TO_CHAR(inSEGMENT)||' '||
    'WHERE PERIOD_YEAR = '||inPERIOD_YEAR||' ';         ...... Note the 'WHERE PERIOD_YEAR' ......

Comment: But syntax is the least of my worries. What I need is a T-SQL equivalent for the oracle structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulation of CONNECT BY PRIOR of ORACLE in SQL SERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server)

Comment: For the record, I've used [..] to help me identify between column names and keywords. I've also added line breaks and tabs, etc. I'm not a SQL expert, and the raw sql is unformatted!

Comment: [Simulation of CONNECT BY PRIOR of ORACLE in SQL SERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server) is almost but not quite. It doesn't explain to me how to handle LEVEL or ORDER SIBLINGS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Simulating the LEVEL column

The level column can easily be simulated by incrementing a counter in the recursive part:

```
WITH tree (empid, name, level) AS  (
  SELECT empid, name, 1 as level
  FROM emp
  WHERE name = 'Joan'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT child.empid, child.name, parent.level + 1
  FROM emp as child
    JOIN tree parent on parent.empid = child.mgrid
)
SELECT name 
FROM tree;
```

---

### Simulating `order siblings by`

Simulating the `order siblings by` is a bit more complicated. Assuming we have a column `sort_order` that defines the order of elements per parent (not the overall sort order - because then `order siblings` wouldn't be necessary) then we can create a column which gives us an overall sort order:

```
WITH tree (empid, name, level, sort_path) AS  (
  SELECT empid, name, 1 as level, 
         cast('/' + right('000000' + CONVERT(varchar, sort_order), 6) as varchar(max))
  FROM emp
  WHERE name = 'Joan'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT child.empid, child.name, parent.level + 1, 
         parent.sort_path + '/' + right('000000' + CONVERT(varchar, child.sort_order), 6) 
  FROM emp as child
    JOIN tree parent on parent.empid = child.mgrid
)
SELECT * 
FROM tree
order by sort_path;
```

The expression for the `sort_path` looks so complicated because SQL Server (at least the version you are using) does not have a simple function to format a number with leading zeros. In Postgres I would use an integer array so that the conversion to `varchar` isn't necessary - but that doesn't work in SQL Server either.

Comment: OK. Thanks, I like that. That's 'LEVEL' sorted. :)  Any idea how to handle ORDER SIBLINGS?

Comment: Yes! This looks like it might work. Assuming that sort_order column is already just a text string something like 'R301 - Area Management' or 'R402 - Casual Staff' - then it should just work ... I hope. The original Oracle code seems to only sort by the 'child'. It displays the 'parent_code' separately for every line in the results. ... I'm trying this now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The option given by the user "a_horse_with_no_name" worked for me. I changed the code and applied it to a menu generator query and it worked the first time. Here is the code:

```
WITH tree(option_id,
       option_description,
      option_url,
      option_icon,
      option_level,
      sort_path)
     AS (
     SELECT ppo.option_id,
            ppo.option_description,
          ppo.option_url,
          ppo.option_icon,
          1 AS option_level,
          CAST('/' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ppo.option_index), 6) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
     FROM security.options_table_name ppo
     WHERE ppo.option_parent_id IS NULL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT co.option_id,
            co.option_description,
          co.option_url,
          co.option_icon,
          po.option_level + 1,
          po.sort_path + '/' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, co.option_index), 6)
     FROM security.options_table_name co,
          tree AS po
     WHERE po.option_id = co.option_parent_id)
     SELECT *
     FROM tree
    ORDER BY sort_path;
```

Answer (score 0):

to get dates for last 10 days:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RecordDate = DATEADD(DAY,-number,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
FROM master..[spt_values] 
WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```