# SQL Server - Get Parent and Ancestor PK

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012, I have a table called [Area]. This table contains a PK and a ParentPK. The ParentPk references the PK from the same [Area] table recursively. If there is no parent, then null is filled in for ParentPk.

```
Pk     ParentPk
----------------
1      null
2      null
3      1
4      3
...
```

I know that the ancestor-child relationship is exactly 3 levels deep. In the above example, The Pk:4 has its parentPk:3 and grandParentPk:1.

I want to be able have a SELECT query be in the form:

```
SELECT GrandParentPk, ParentPk, ChildPk
...
...
...
where ChildPk = <childPk>
```

Is there a non stored procedure, non recursive solution to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Equivalent of Oracle 'CONNECT BY PRIOR', and 'ORDER SIBLINGS BY'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827817/sql-server-equivalent-of-oracle-connect-by-prior-and-order-siblings-by)

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are always querying using the last child `pk`, and the hierarchy is always three levels, you can just use two `inner join`s.

```
select gp.pk as GrandParentPk, p.pk as ParentPk, c.pk as ChildPk
from Area c
  inner join Area p
    on c.parentPk = p.pk
  inner join Area gp 
    on p.parentPk = gp.pk
where c.pk = 4
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MSXTVR55260

returns:

```
+---------------+----------+---------+
| GrandParentPk | ParentPk | ChildPk |
+---------------+----------+---------+
|             1 |        3 |       4 |
+---------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: That's a great solution! Sometimes, the basics are the best answer