# Convert Oracle query to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

I am facing a problem to convert an Oracle query to its SQL Server 2008 version. In this Oracle query `LISTAGG` and `connect by prior` are used. I researched the web to find that `WITH AS ()` is `connect by prior` equivalent in SQL Server 2008.

Also for `LISTAGG` alternate in SQL Server 2008 we can use `STUFF()`. But I'm facing difficulty in integrate these two logics into one. Please help me. The solution I tried seems to be wrong.

Here, is the Oracle query:

```
SELECT
    (LISTAGG(T1.c2, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T1.c1)) 
FROM 
    Table1 T1 
START WITH T1.c1 = T2.c3 
CONNECT BY PRIOR T1.c3 = T1.c1
```

This is the solution I tried:

```
with n(col1, col2) as 
(
    select T1.c1, '/' + T1.c2
    from table1 T1,
    where T1.c1 = T2.c3
    union ALL
    select T3.c1, '/' + T3.c2
    from table1 as T4,T3
    where T4.c3 = T3.c1  
)
select col2 from n;
```

Here in the both the queries `T2` is a reference for a `Table2` that is used in an outer query.

Ex:

```
Select 
.....,
.....,
.
.
(
  select (LISTAGG(T1.c2, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T1.c1)) 
  FROM Table1 T1 
  start with T1.c1 = T2.c3 
  connect by prior T1.c3 = T1.c1
) as ABC,
'
'
'
From
Table A,
Table B,
.
.
Table T2
```

Links I referred ::

- [Connect By Prior Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server)
- [LISTAGG Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 0):

`LISTAGG` you can se [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver).

`With` you can do like this in SQL:

```
select * into #n from
(
    select T1.c1 col1, '/' + T1.c2 col2
    from table1 T1,
    where T1.c1 = T2.c3
    union ALL
    select T3.c1, '/' + T3.c2
    from table1 as T4,T3
    where T4.c3 = T3.c1  
)
```